# Idea for improving heapsort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort

I am trying to propose an enhanced heapsort that would combine the min and max. I got the concept of this from the Double Selection Sort which works by finding the min and max values in the array and placing the max into the last index and the min in the starting index. How do i apply this to the heapsort?
For visualization, this is what i want to happen:
Original Array Form:

```
[9, 1, 15, 2, 10]
9
/ \
1 15
/ \
2 10
```

Heapsort with min-max combination:

```
15
/ \
1 9
/ \
2 10

15
/ \
2 9
/ \
1 10
```

in this part, the second to the last element within the binary tree assumes the role of the minimum, while the maximum value is preserved. Specifically, in our example, the second-to-last value of the binary tree is 1, representing the minimum, while the max heapify is performed for the value 15.

```
10
/ \
2 9
/ \
1 15
```

here, the 1 will be place in the starting index and the 15 will be place in the last index.

```
[1, ,15]

10
/ \
2 9

9
/ \
2 10
```

here, the max heapify is performed, and min is stay put since the 2 is the lowest value and is already placed in the second to the last index. and then, they will be deleted from the tree and be sorted in the array.
`[1, 2, 10, 15]`

9
since, 9 is the only one left, it will be then deleted and inserted in the array.
`[1, 2, 9, 10, 15] SORTED`

1. Is this applicable?
2. What ways or steps do I need to implement this?

I tried coding this but its not working.

Comment: Hello. Awesome idea! It's a bit hard to follow your manipulations on the `[9, 1, 15, 2, 10]` array. The main issue I can see with your idea is this: the heap has the property that it's always easy to extract the minimum (if it's a min-heap), or it's always easy to extract the maximum (if it's a max-heap). From your description it sounds like you're trying to make a new data structure which is a variation of the heap, and which has the property that it's always easy to extract both the minimum and the minimum. I don't know about this data structure and it's unclear to me what it would look like

Comment: yeah. it's a bit challenging to follow. the goal is not to create a new data structure but rather to modify the heapsort algorithm wherein it simultaneously finds the min and max and sorts them accordingly. however, i am having a hard time to implement this since i am also not sure if this is applicable or if this idea can improve the speed of heapsort.

Comment: Yes, but the heapsort algorithm relies on a heap to extract the maximum. If you want to be able to extract both the maximum and the minimum, then a heap is not going to work as-is: if it's a max-heap there will be no easy way to retrieve the minimum, and if it's a min-heap there will be no easy way to retrieve the maximum. So it sounds like you want a data structure which, although maybe similar to a heap, is not exactly a heap.

Comment: There is a [min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap) by the way

Comment: @user166089 Where would the performance improvement come from, both for this and for "double selection sort"? Both algorithms would be doing half as many steps, but twice as much work in each step. You'd have to look at nitty-gritty details like effects of e.g. cache locality. The asymptotic time complexity is unaffected in both cases (and can't be affected in the case of heapsort, since linearithmic is already optimal).

Comment: can you explain further, please? on what ways i can implement this?

Comment: yeah, there is a min-max heap but its process is alternate of max heap and min heap

Comment: @user166089 since you want to find min & max in each step, you'll either need a min-max heap as linked by harold, or you'll need to give up on working in-place and maintain both a min heap and a max heap, one of which will need to not be "in-place".

Comment: @user166089 Are you familiar with other tree-based sorts? If you have a data structure like a binary search tree or a heap or some other kind of ordered tree, it's easy to write a sorting algorithm that relies on this data structure: 1) build the tree with the elements in the array; 2) Retrieve elements from the tree in order and put them in their place in the array.

Comment: yeah but that would not be heapsort anymore, right? but i am focusing on the improvement of heapsort.

Comment: @user166089 The reason why heapsort is much more popular than other tree-based sorts is that if you use a max-heap, then you can store the heap inside the array while you're sorting it, which is a bit of a magic trick. But try implementing heapsort with a minheap instead of a maxheap and you'll see that this "inplace trick" no longer really works; and you'll run into the same issue with a minmax heap.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by this distinction between "improvement of heapsort" and "not heapsort anymore" ;-) The moment you try to improve heapsort, of course it's no longer heapsort. If I add chocolate to a vanilla ice cream, then it's no longer a vanilla ice cream, it's a vanilla-and-chocolate ice cream.

Comment: @Stef so basically, this idea of mine is not realistically applicable?

Comment: @user166089 I didn't say that. In fact I literally said that you could make a sorting algorithm by simply moving the elements of the array from the array to a minmax heap, then retrieving them. Now if you want to make an in-place sort like heapsort, it's going to be a lot more trouble. But not necessarily impossible.

Comment: @user166089 For heapsort, if the array has n elements, then the array is cut into two parts: cells 0 to k-1 contain the k smallest elements, that are still in the heap, and cells k to n-1 contain the n-k largest elements, that have already been sorted.

Comment: @user166089 For your minmaxheapsort, you'd need the array to be cut into three parts: cells 0 to j-1 containing the j smallest elements, which have already been sorted; cells n-j to n-1 containing the j largest elements, which have already been sorted; and cells j to n-j-1 containing the n-2j most-median elements, which are still in the minmaxheap. But note the difficulty here: this means that the operation "extract min and max from heap" must move the heap from [j, n-j-1] to [j+1, n-j-2] in the array.

Comment: Whereas in standard heapsort, the operation "extract max from heap" moves the heap from [0, k-1] to [0, k-2] in the array.